# Java audio input lightorgran

Tags: java, python, audio

In time for the holidays I would like to take part in my companies cubicle decoration competition. I am planning on setting up a raspberry pi with pi face to power 5v Christmas lights to the sheet music of a song. I know I could easily hard code this to follow along to the music, which Is my current plan.

I was wondering however if there is some way that I could listen to the stream of outgoing audio and manipulate the lights according to outputs based of frequency. lets say there are 8 channels of lights. 2 would cover 0-200hz 3 channels would cover 200-5000hz and 3 would cover 5000-10000hz. While I wait for my pi face to arrive I was planning on doing some basic testing in java. Then I would rewrite the code for python. I was wondering if there was a way to do accomplish my idea in java and them also a way to preform the final implementation in python.

Comment: Without any context, this is (too) broad. But of course you can read raw audio from a file or `/dev/audio` in Java and show some changing images in a Swing UI, or just some printlns on `System.out` that you would have switched the Christmas lights if you had any attached to your JVM.

Comment: Is there a way that you can read the live output that is being sent out to the speakers? And then interpret the data based on the frequency of the sound being output? So lets say your listen to a video on youtube, the audio being output to the speakers, can it be "listened" to and be transformed into some type of meaningful value such as hertz. Then this value could be used to trigger each specific channel of lights.

Comment: I'm sure that there are ways (that are quite operating-system dependent). But have you written the algorithm? I would focus on that to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible using FFT/frequency analysis, but a RaspberryPi does not have the computational power. I built something similar but based on MIDI. MIDI is a music protocol/format to play music/control music instruments. MIDI files contain data about music notes which can be mapped easily to channels and control light circuits.

My code is open source (https://github.com/mp911de/midi-relay) and written in Java. Should be possible to read MIDI also using Python. The other thing is, you need to control somehow your lights. GPIO does not provide enough power to operate christmas lights (my LED circuits need about 0,5A@24V (about 12W). This means, you have to use some sort of controllable switch/relay with external power supply. I used an ethernet-controllable relay for this.

This year, I put my christmas lights online, you can find the code at https://github.com/mp911de/heckenlights and the site at http://heckenlights.org. The Github code contains some schematics on how to connect and control lights.